# How to compare 2 columns in GlideRecord.addQuery() method?

Tags: servicenow

Assuming I have a table data as:

```
id    col_1    col_2
----------------------  
11    10000    20000
12    13000    10000
```

Is it possible to retrieve `id`s for which `col_1 < col_2`?. So the expected output here is `id:11`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You an compare fields with special field comparison operators:

```
var gr = new GlideRecord("u_table_name");
gr.addQuery("col_1", "SAMEAS", "col_2"); // i.e. WHERE col_1 = col_2
gr.query();
```

The operators that allow comparing two different fields on the same table:

- `SAMEAS`: field = other field
- `NSAMEAS`: field != other field
- `GT_FIELD`: field > other field
- `LT_FIELD`: field < other field
- `GT_OR_EQUALS_FIELD`: field >= other field
- `LT_OR_EQUALS_FIELD`: field <= other field

When in doubt, you can always write a GlideRecord query for anything that's supported by the filter UI. Just build the filter you want in the UI, run it, then right-click the breadcrumbs (just above the filter builder UI), and select "Copy URL". 
This will give you the Encoded query URL which you can either just paste directly into the GlideRecord api `gr.addEncodedQuery(...)` or deconstruct using the 3-argument `gr.addQuery(columnName, operatorName, value)`, where in the case of the dynamic field comparison operators, the `value` arg is the *other* column name.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is definitely possible. The first thing that comes to my mind about field comparison are list filters. You need to try and validate if it is possible to filter out these record from a list view. If yes, you can surely query on them using the GlideRecord API. If they cannot be queried, we also have other options like dynamic filters or even a database view could help.

So I added a sample table for the data, You need to make sure the columns are of Integer Type and applied my filter on it

[image: Filter]

The related query was copied from filter as u_col_1LT_FIELDu_col_2. You can fetch different encoded queries depending on the filter operator.

Now the next step is to make a table query to fetch your required Ids.

```js
var myTable = new GlideRecord('u_custom_table'); //Table to query
myTable.addEncodedQuery('u_col_1LT_FIELDu_col_2');  //Replace your filter query
myTable.query();
while(myTable.next()){
 gs.print("Id: "+myTable.u_id); //Replace id column
}
```

and the output when executed via background script

[image]

The same approach can be applied to query any records from a Service Now table.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not possible to do it in a GlideRecord query. We don't have acces to sql anymore so I think it is not possible at all.

But if you can add a column in your table, you could do like this :

```
id    col_1    col_2   sup
---------------------------  
11    10000    20000   true
12    13000    10000   false
```

You could set the sup flag with Insert & update business rule, so you could query the sup field in the GlideRecord query.

Comment: I am afraid I cannot do that. I said `Table` in question for simplicity, in reality it's a db view. Thanks for confirming that what I am expecting is not possible. I already proceeded with custom JS code for it.